# How to do URL mapping in Crafter 3.0

Tags: crafter-cms

I was wondering if crafter (3.0) has the ability to do url mapping.

For example, to have a content at a given path like `/site/website/foobar/mycontent/index.xml`, and its url being `/news/2017/11/17/my-content` (notice the added `/` which can't be used in a `file-name` field since they are automatically converted to `-` in studio).

Thanks,

Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A built-in router is on our roadmap (https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/1622), but for now, you can add one to your blueprint easily:

1. Create a component that contains a "routing table". This component
   has a repeating table where each entry is an inbound URL and
   outbound URL.
2. Create a Groovy filter script that will intercept all calls and
   checks if the URL matches one of the inbound URLs. If it does, it
   forwards the request to the corresponding outbound URL. Below is the
   possible code for such filter:

   ```
   def routingTableItem = siteItemService.getSiteItem("/site/components/system/routing-table.xml")
   def routingTable = routingTableItem.urlRoutingTable.item
   def currentURL = request.requestURI

   def matchedEntry = routingTable.find { entry ->
       return currentURL == entry.inboundURL.text
   }

   if (matchedEntry) {
       def inboundURL = matchedEntry.inboundURL.text
       def outboundURL = matchedEntry.outboundURL.text

       logger.info("Forwarding URL ${inboundURL} to ${outboundURL}")

       request.getRequestDispatcher(outboundURL).forward(request, response)
   } else {
       filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
   }
   ```